# Unable to insert data using @OneToMany Spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to insert employee record with List using @OneToMany mapping.

Entity Class Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer employeeId;

    @Column(name = "employee_name")
    private String employeeName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(allowSetters = true, value = { "employee" })
    private List<EmployeePayroll> employeePayroll;

}
```

Entity Class EmployeePayroll:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EmployeeSalary")
public class EmployeePayroll {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long salary;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fromDate;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date toDate;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

}
```

Request body:

```
{
    "employeeName":"krishna",
    "employeePayroll":[
        {
            "salary":200,
            "fromDate":"2015-01-01",
            "toDate":"2017-02-02"
        }
    ]   
}
```

Service method:

```
public Integer createEmployee(Employee employee) {
    Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);

    return savedEmployee.getEmployeeId();
}
```

When I tried to call the API, I got org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException.

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

MYSQL Logs:

```
Query   insert into employee (employee_name) values ('krishna')
Query   insert into employee_salary (employee_id, from_date, salary, to_date) values (null, '2015-01-01', 200, '2017-02-02')
```

Looks like employee_id (Employee) value is not set to the EmployeePayroll entity on post insertof Employee.

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: did you specify a MySql dialect in your Hibernate configuration?

Comment: @rena  Yes, specified the dialect

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the reference bidirectional : from EmployeePayroll -> Employee

One simple way is to set the reference before saving it:

```
employee.getEmployeePayroll().forEach(EmployeePayroll::setEmployee);
```

and after save it:

```
Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
```